# Sharepoint 2010 Data Sources with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-authentication

This is two part questions: 
Does SharePoint 2010 support Trusted_Connection(Integrated Security=Yes;) when connecting to SQL Servers 2008/2012 for retrieving custom list?

If it does how can I set it up?

Currently I tried to go to Data Sources, clicked on new Database Connection. 
Selected "User custom connection string" inserted connection string in the following format

v1. `Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=Yes;`

v2. `Server=ServerName;Database=databaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;`

v3. `Server=ServerName;Database=databaseName;Integrated Security=Yes;`

I get the same error message with all the different combinations. 
"Server Error: An error occured while retrieving the list of Databases from ServerName: The server for the data source returned a non-specific error when trying to execute your query. Check the format and content of your query and thy again. If the problem persists, contact the server administrator."

note: I do not want/can not use SQL Authentication so don't even suggest it.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions where I can find the error log for my error? Should I be looking on SharePoint server or the SQL Server? This morning I have started SQL Server Profiler and enable most areas that would be relevant to connection but I stil did not see anything in the Trace file that would be connected to the error message.

From my SharePoint server, I went to central administrator and enabled all logging. Replicated the error message but still did not find the error in log.

Comment: you can try to look in the uls log formsharepoint. there will be logged all events from sharepoint.

Comment: We have to make few changes in "manage service applications" under central administration to enable windows authentication or Single sign on authentication. The below link gives complete description about how to do it. Hope this helps :) [For Windows authentication to connect to external data source](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/09/25/how-to-create-data-sources-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-part-ii.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some mistake in query and not in connection string.

pls make sure that the query is ...

SELECT Name FROM master.sys.databases

Comment: I don't get to the query part, once I feel in connection string and hit next I get the error.

Comment: Sorry...Not clear to me...Why don't you post the whole code related to it and clearly mention which line you are getting the error.

Comment: I posted 3 different connection strings, I said that I tried 3 different ways to use the same connection string not sure where you found the query?

Comment: Oh Man! The connection string correct. There somewhere else where you are making the mistake.